# Offline Domain disjoin

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory

Is there any way to dis-join a machine from a domain without it being connected to the domain. I had a machine die, and built up a new one with the same name, well, after we got the laptop back from RMA they didn't erase the hard drive as expected, so I'd like to dis-join it from the domain and rejoin it with a new name without screwing up the system that has replaced it.(the other computer is off site and its user is on vacation)

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out, I just had to go through with a regular dis-join, not provide credentials(just hit enter when it asked for admin username/password), and it dis-joined.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, you can simply switch to a workgroup.  Before you add it to the domain again, though, you may need to delete the computer account through `Active Directory Users and Computers`.

The reason it prompts you for credentials when leaving a domain is that it will clean up the computer account.  You will have missed this step by disjoining offline.

Comment: Well, i created an account already that uses the same exact name. So I really want to avoid that because there's a system out there that needs that information to stay in AD!